# Angular and jQuery ng-include with document.ready not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, document-ready, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to load a component which is placed in a separate html using HMTL. The problem is that it is to be invoked as soon as the page is loaded in the browser.

Below is my Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade borderColorC0C0C0 borderRadiusOverride" id="termsAndConditionsPopover" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" ng-include="'components/popover/termsAndConditions/termsAndConditions.html'">

</div>
```

The component code is here:

**termsAndConditions.html**

```
<div class="modal-dialog borderRadiusOverride">
    <div class="modal-content borderRadiusOverride">
      <div class="termsAndConditionsHeaderColor borderRadiusOverride divHeight50 paddingTop15 paddingLeft15 paddingBottom15 borderBottomColorC0C0C0">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>-->
        <h5 class="modal-title marginBottom15 fontColorTileSteps" id="myModalLabel">Cisco's GSA shipping Policy</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body borderRadiusOverride fontColorTileSteps">
        This policy outlines the requirements of shipping Internationally including but not limited to:
<ul>
    <li>All members of the Cisco workforce are responsible to adhere to this policy</li>
    <li>AST is to not be used for personal shipments</li>
    <li>Prohibited items</li>
    <li>Textiles</li>
    <li>Shipments to Trade shows, hotels, residential addresses</li>
    <li>Importer of record requirements</li>
    <li>Shipment of used equipment</li>
    <li>Other restrictions; including export requirements</li>
</ul>
<p>Fixed Assets shipping from one Cisco entity to another Cisco entity must transfer the value to the receiving entity. It is the responsibility of the person initiating the shipment to ensure this takes place. Please refer to the Asset Management System. AMS is used in US, India, China and Brazil. The asset tracking process will vary for the rest of the countries.</p>

<p><strong>PLEASE NOTE:</strong> The person initiating the shipment is responsible for the accuracy of all shipment information. Should fines be levied due to misinformation given by individual, all associated costs will be charged to your Department.</p>

<p>In International transactions governmental agencies have the power to request evidence to attest to the information given on commercial documentation, either at importation or in subsequent audits. International shipments may be subject to export and/or import licenses. The recipient of the international shipment may be required to obtain import licensing based on the destination country or address (business/residential) or the goods contained within the shipment.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="textAlignCenter borderRadiusOverride">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttonColor525252 termsAndConditionsButton marginTop10 marginBottom30 fontColorWhite" data-dismiss="modal">I have read and I comply with Cisco's GSA shipping Policy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The Way I am invoking the modal using JavaScript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#termsAndConditionsPopover').modal('show');
});
```

The problem is: if I **dont use** ng-include this works fine. But when I use **ng-include** it **does not work**. I think that **ng-include** is not getting executed first and hence the modal is not getting loaded. Is there any solution to this?

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: try with `$(window).load(fn)`

Comment: There's a `$includeContentLoaded` event, though unfortunately not particularly well documented. You probably need to initiate `.modal()` in a handler attached to that event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The modal dialog definitely needs to be initiated on some later event than `document.ready`. It's just a question of deciding which is the best event.

`window.load` is the most obvious event to try but is not a particularly "Angular" approach.

The earliest reliable event would be the completion of loading of the dialog div, and Angular provides for this with a `$includeContentLoaded` event.

To demonstrate the principle, here's a demo with content loaded from a local template and with jQueryUI's `.dialog()` :

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="demo">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
            <p>This is included text</p>
        </script>
        <div id="termsAndConditionsPopover" ng-include src="templates.modal" ng-controller="ModalCtrl"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*Note that the `ng-include` and `ng-controller` directives work in consortium to achieve the objective of triggering an action when the content (determined by the the `src` attribute) has loaded*

**Javascript**

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

demo.controller('AppController', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.templates = {
        modal: 'modal.html'
    };
}]);

demo.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
        $('#termsAndConditionsPopover').dialog({ autoOpen: true });
    });
}]);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdg2y75w/)

There's still some work to do though not a lot. Your final code should be largely a simplification of the above as you don't need the local template or the associated `$rootScope.templates` map.

Comment: Excellent, pleased to help.